# edits to txt file with batch make them grow bigger

Tags: batch-file, cmd

any time i use batch to edit a signal line of text (really it just one character that changes) the file gets a little bigger. it shouldn't do that if the amount of text is the same again one character.

what I'm trying to do is launch a program (an emulator called blueMSX) and have it so the bat changes a setting according to what I put in. since the devs I guess didn't feel it necessary to put in robust command line capabilities beyond the basics i have to do it by changing a line in the config ini.

While it does work somehow extra data is being tacked on. Not only does this mean the file will get bigger and bigger every time its used by the bat but worse still the emulator i guess dosn't like it either and just adds in completely new settings after the old. and before anyone ask no the extra data is not the new settings as I have tested this without starting the program at all and just changing the text. here is the code in question

```
@echo off
:again
set alright=n

echo Enter 5 for 50hz or 6 for 60hz
set /p strUserInput=50hz or 60hz:

if %strUserInput%==5 (
    set alright=y
)

if %strUserInput%==6 (
    set alright=y
)

if %alright%==n goto again


setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

break > "%CD%\blueMSXv282full\bluemsxTemp.ini"

set strLineToChange=emulation.vdpSyncMode^=

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=~" %%a  in ("%CD%\blueMSXv282full\bluemsx.ini") do (

    set strLine=%%a

    IF "!strLine:~0,22!"=="%strLineToChange%" (
        echo %strLineToChange%%strUserInput%0Hz >> "%CD%\blueMSXv282full\bluemsxTemp.ini"
    ) ELSE (
        echo %%a >> "%CD%\blueMSXv282full\bluemsxTemp.ini"
    )

)

del "%CD%\blueMSXv282full\bluemsx.ini"
rename "%CD%\blueMSXv282full\bluemsxTemp.ini" "bluemsx.ini"

start /D "%CD%\blueMSXv282full\" "blueMSX.exe" "%CD%\blueMSXv282full\blueMSX.exe" -rom1 "%~1"
```

one more thing if i make the edit manually with notepad it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    echo %strLineToChange%%strUserInput%0Hz >> "%CD%\blueMSXv282full\bluemsxTemp.ini"
) ELSE (
    echo %%a >> "%CD%\blueMSXv282full\bluemsxTemp.ini"
```

The spaces before the `>>` will be output to the file, try

```
    echo %strLineToChange%%strUserInput%0Hz>> "%CD%\blueMSXv282full\bluemsxTemp.ini"
) ELSE (
    echo %%a>> "%CD%\blueMSXv282full\bluemsxTemp.ini"
```